# FeedMe - Import to multi language sites, linking entries

Tags: craft3, multi-site, plugin-feedme

How does one use FeedMe to import content to a multi language setup? I can have one feed with all languages, or a feed for each language, but I cannot see how to set the locale of the import content, nor then how to link them as tranlsations of the same entry.

The documentation here does not seem to include info about it:
https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/

There is a small paragraph about Target Site, but I do not have that option on my multi-site install, and it does not detail how to link entries together.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to:

1. Set Entries to propagate across all sites for you chosen section
2. Import your main language (which will propagate to all your sites)
3. Using ID's (or else) to match elements, import second language to update previously propagated entries and correct content.

[Here's an article explaining the process](https://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/importing-entries-into-a-multi-lingual-craft-cms-website/).

Comment: Thanks I will take a look, sounds a bit long winded though. Just looking in the database, I can see ElementId looks to be the connection between pages, its a real shame you cant pass ElementId or SiteID in the FeedMe import that would be such a simple solution then.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. ElementId isn't known until one entry is in and with siteId you'd still need a common point to relate entries together? If anything, having them as 'children' of a 'parent' could work.

Comment: I just looked in the database and all the languages of a single entry have the same ElementId. I assumed this the relationship between them.

Comment: Oh sure, I just mean that you need to know it before you use it. Your entry needs to be created then this elementId needs to be associated with the other languages for that entry.